# telegram webhook passing no data(ssl is ok)

Tags: php, json, ssl, bots, telegram

https://api.telegram.org/bottoken/setWebhook?url=https://urltomybot.php

Returns Webhook was set. I have not self-signed ssl cerftificate, so path to public certificate file not needed.

```
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$data = json_decode($json, true);
var_dump($json);
var_dump($data);
```

returns

> string(0) "" NULL

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that I'm generating empty query buy visiting this page, lolz.

```
file_put_contents('data.txt', $json);
```

helped. So now I got json array in data.txt